# How do I access another user's data by a specific field?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to make a user send their num to another user.
I created a random keycode for every user to send each other a num.

I tried accessing the data by querying them.

```
     const sendNum = async(e) => {
        const userCol = collection(db, "users")  
        e.preventDefault();
        

        const targetQuery = query(userCol, where("keycode", "==", target))
        const targetSnapshot = await getDocs(targetQuery)
        
        targetSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            console.log(doc.data().num);
        })
        console.log(targetSnapshot);
```

But it returns an object rather than the another user's num field

```
Nu {_firestore: xc, _userDataWriter: ah, _snapshot: Oo, metadata: Su, query: Ic}
```

Here's what the data looks like:

[image]

Comment: We can't see the value of `target`, so we don't know if your query is returning what you expect from the data you show.  Printing the `targetSnapshot` is not going to be helpful as it doesn't show query results.  The snapshot object will always print something non-null, even if there are no query results.  Please edit the question to be more complete with your debugging details.

Comment: no it was already defined the user will input it. I inputed it as the the target's keycode.

Comment: But we don't know if the value is what you think.  There is no evidence here that it contains the value you expect.  Hard code the value to be sure, or show the [complete minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that anyone can run to observe the results that don't make sense.

Comment: Thanks! I hard coded the value and it worked.

Comment: It must've been an issue with the input. And it logged the object because I logged the entire targetSnapshot. Very silly mistake. but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting the solution suggested by Doug Stevenson as a Community Wiki for visibility.

From the description it's not possible to tell what value the `target` holds.
In this case, hard coding the value worked to access the user field.